# filter dataframe by combination of observations from the same column

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataframe:

```
bigDf <- data.frame(sampleType = c("D","D","D","P1", "P2","D","P3","D","P1")
                    ,patient= c("x17","x17","x18","x18","x18","x19","x19","x20","x20"))
```

It looks like this:

```
> bigDf
  sampleType patient
1          D     x17
2          D     x17
3          D     x18
4         P1     x18
5         P2     x18
6          D     x19
7         P3     x19
8          D     x20
9         P1     x20
```

I would like to only keep rows that come from `patients` that have both `D` and `P1` `sampleTypes`, and reject `patients` that have one or none of these, as well as rows with sample types other than `D` and `P1` (even if I keep other rows from the same `patient`).

My desired output is this:

```
> outputDf
  sampleType patient
1          D     x18
2         P1     x18
3          D     x20
4         P1     x20
```

I know I have to `group_by(patient)`, but don't know how to only keep one row if another one is present.

EDIT: I changed the `bigDF` slightly to show more than `P2` `sampleType` might have to be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
bigDf %>%
    group_by(patient) %>% 
    filter(all(c("D", "P1") %in% sampleType),
        !sampleType  %in% c("P2", "P3")) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  sampleType patient
  <chr>      <chr>  
1 D          x18    
2 P1         x18    
3 D          x20    
4 P1         x20
```

Comment: That's a slick use of `all()` in `filter()` to get the distinct groupings.

Comment: In my real-life dataset I have more than one ```sampleType``` that I want to reject. I edited your answer to this to make it work:

```'%notin%' <- Negate("%in%") bigDf %>%
  group_by(patient) %>% 
  filter(all(c("D", "P1") %in% sampleType) & sampleType %notin% c("P2", "P3")) %>% 
  ungroup```

Comment: @Wera Okay sir.  I didn't realize that you had multiple elements.  Sorry for making that mistake

Comment: No problem at all, I should have been clearer:) i have edited the original post to make it unambiguous!